# SQL Server string concatenation returns blank

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please help me with this challenge.

This code returns a **blank result** and I can't figure out the reason.

[image]

```
select Vendor_Name + ' || ' + cast(cnt as varchar(12)) as Vendor_Count
from (select top (1) Vendor_Name, count(Vendor_Name) as cnt 
      from dbo.Vendors nolock 
      group by Vendor_Name 
      having count(Vendor_Name)>1 
      order by 2 desc) x
```

But...The inner query returns the **Vendor_Name blank, and cnt 63420**

[image]

```
select top (1) 
    Vendor_Name, count(Vendor_Name) as cnt 
from 
    dbo.Vendors nolock 
group by 
    Vendor_Name 
having 
    count(Vendor_Name) > 1 
order by 
    2 desc
```

Here is the the result of the inner query without the top (1). As you can see, the blank/empty/null Vendor_Name occurs most frequently.

[image]

I check the length of Vendor_name using len() function, and it returns 12. But when i copy the result from the inner query above to an excel sheet, and use the len() function in Excel - excel shows 0. The declared length for `Vendor_name` in the SQL Server table is `nvarchar(50)`.

I tried `isnull(Vendor_Name,'')` and `COALESCE(Vendor_Name,'')` but that didn't make a difference.

I re-arranged the query and got non-blank result, it is interesting that this works but my original query doesn't.

```
select ' || ' + cast(cnt as varchar(12)) + ' ' + Vendor_Name  
from (select top (1) Vendor_Name, count(Vendor_Name) as cnt 
      from dbo.Vendors nolock 
      group by Vendor_Name 
      having count(Vendor_Name)>1 
      order by 2 desc) x
```

But this result is not what i wanted.

Did i miss something?

Thank you!

ps.
I have tried to replicate the data to to post it here but without success.

Comment: Do you mean really blank ' ', or empty '' or null?

Comment: Aside: 'tis a bold coder that uses `order by 2`.  You must not have done a lot of maintenance on other people's code yet.

Comment: @automatic Can`t be `null` because of the `having`

Comment: Can you show screenshots of what you are experiencing. Don't really follow your description.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Wouldn't a NULL `Vendor_Name` result in a valid count, but a failed concatenation?

Comment: @HABO `count(null)` would be `0` so wouldn't be `>1`

Comment: @ToDo I'm suspecting this *might* be to do with mixing nvarchar and varchar types in the concatenation - have you tried playing around with these?

Comment: @automatic i tried copy the result and paste on excel and nothing is there (empty?). If there are empty characters i would know because it should show in excel when you click on the cell - you'll see the cursor is in somewhere in the cell other than at the beginning of the cell.

Comment: @ToDo Wouldn't put too much faith in copying into Excel. As you say Vendor_Name is a nvarchar type, it's just possible there could be unicode characters that don't display/copy properly (...seems pretty suspicious that len() returns 12.)

Comment: i added some screenshots.

Comment: @SteveChambers i played around with the nvarchar too but that didn't help.
As i mentioned in my post, when i put the Vendor_Name after the count then it would work.

Comment: @ToDo Thanks for trying. After scratching my head for quite a while think I might have come up with a possibile explanation - see answer below...

Comment: Please do `CAST(Vendor_Name AS VARBINARY(24))` and let us know what that says.

Comment: @MartinSmith i tried, but got error msg **Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types varbinary and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.**

Comment: Steve Chambers provided the solution that solved my problem. Thanks everyone for your inputs!

Comment: Don't try and concatenate the result. Just `SELECT CAST(Vendor_Name AS VARBINARY(24)) FROM ... ` so we can see exactly what characters are stored.

Comment: @MartinSmith it returns 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Am suspecting Vendor_Name might start with a `NUL` (`'\0'`) character indicating end-of-string. This would make it *seem* to have no content and explain the difference in concatenation order.

To test this, please try `REPLACE(Vendor_Name, CHAR(0), ' ')` in your outer query

Comment: You've nailed it Steve! Thank you!